# puppeteer/playwright: How to get Authorization: Bearer token and pass to request (eg axios)?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, playwright

I'm logged in to the web page, navigate to the destination web page with puppeteer/playwright and want to download a csv file with request.

The request headers include Authorization: "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV......"

is it possible to get Authorization: "Bearer Token" from puppeteer/playwright and submit it to request (eg axios).

Thnx a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution:

```
 var accessTokenObj = await crPage.evaluate(() => {
      return localStorage.getItem("TokenName");
    });
```

an then put accessTokenObj into axios header
Authorization: `Bearer ${accessTokenObj}`

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find crPage,I used page from playwright to get authorization token.

var token = page.evaluate(localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
playwright [docs](https://www.example.com/) ! for page.evaluate()